# How to link Vue.JS page from my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am creating a website, however the home page is created in regular HTML/CSS. My other page is created in Vue.js.

Is there a way I can link both files?  For example can I create a button on the first HTML page, which takes me to the 2nd page created in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy your `Vue.js` application with following command:

```
npm run build
```

This will create the `dist` folder, which you can upload to your server. This process will create a `.html` file, which you can call from your main page.